# git update-index --assume-unchanged - but the file is still occasionally updated

Tags: git

I have a config file on which I ran:

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <name of config file>
```

It's not being tracked but it's still being updated occasionally. No idea how but it's incredibly frustrating.

Any suggestions how I track down exactly what is causing the issue?

Comment: Is this a programming question?

Comment: @BadZen:  Considering that Git is a tool that programmers use, I'd say it's fine to ask...

Comment: What exactly do you mean by updated? Can you post the output of a command to demonstrate that?

Comment: It's a config file. Text is updated. Eg Server = 'localhost'. I'm paraphrasing slightly.

Comment: Do you pull/merge from a remote repository?

Answer (score 1):

`git update-index --assume-unchaged` mainly intends to avoid issues when your [file system has an inefficient `lstat(2)` implementation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_using_assume_unchanged_bit). It's main goal is to improve performance; `assume-unchanged` does not intend to protect the file from upstream changes or hard resets.

What you are truly looking for is `git update-index --skip-worktree`. While the documentation isn't particular obvious in this regard, the `skip-worktree` bit should be used when you have files which **should** be changed locally ([as explained in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13631525/2274224)) while avoiding to commit this changes to the repository.

Sadly the names of `assume-unchanged` and `skip-worktree` communicate their intent very badly, most of the time `skip-worktree` is the superior choice and the correct solution.

Comment: is it possible to also prevent safe changes? From the docs: *Note that Git can update working directory file, that is marked skip-worktree, if it is safe to do so.*

Comment: @user1978011 AFAIK no, it isn't. But if that's what you want, why tracking the file in the first place? Maybe it makes more sense to use a *default file*, and copy it locally. For example if you have an `.env` file your application requires, you could add `.env` to your `.gitignore` while tracking a file named `.env.default` which contains sensible defaults.